# h:selectBooleanCheckbox cannot set value

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, backing-beans

I am trying to bind `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` to its backing bean twin as :

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="jojo" binding="myBean.sbc0" />
```

...and the backing bean :

```
@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean{
...
private HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox sbc0;
...
@PostConstruct
public void initui(){
  sbc0=new HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox();
}

public void doValue(){//h:commandButton ajax event handle method
 this.sbc0.setValue(""+Math.random()); //<---doesn't set value?
}

}
```

...and using js to get value fails **returning 'on'** only

```
var v=document.getElementById("jojo").value;//<---returns 'on' only :(
```

As I can get it, the value may have any string etc *(correct me if I am wrong)*... So my question is what may cause the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: any ideas? Does the HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox allow to set value or not? Share your experience please